# jQuery auto-correct plugin not working on 1.7.2 version

Tags: jquery, autocorrect

I'm using this great plugin: http://www.sanisoft.com/blog/2009/06/22/jquery-auto-correct-plugin/

But it's not working with 1.6.2 or greater...

It works fine up to jQuery v1.5.2.

Do you know how could I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just delete the first if statement in the plugin. Eg, delete this:

```
// If plugin attached to text/textarea field then don't need to proceed further
if (0 > jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).attr("type"), new Array("text", "textarea")))
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Great! Works perfect! Thanks! Not sure what that if statment refers to, but I'm glad it works!

Comment: Looks like they're trying to avoid double-binding the plugin, but you can avoid that yourself by writing good code in the first place :p

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `jQuery.noConflict()`

Possible duplicate - [JQuery Version Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332111/jquery-version-conflict)

And a reference - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-jquery-version-conflict